# Python to Replace Skechup Material to Cycles Material

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm using the Blender to make all my works university (architecture), but in my job the people use Sketchup for modeling and V-Ray for rendering. 
I want use Blender, cause liked more then others, the problem is that to rendering with Cycles, I have to need import the Skp file, change all materials (or set), create lamps etc... How to make a Python script that replace the materials by one list in all objects on the scene?

For example:

- Cube.001 have the material "OldMaterial.01" in one face, and "OldMaterial.02" in others.
- Cube.002 have the material "OldMaterial.02" in one face, and "OldMaterial.03" in others.

And we have the list:

- For "OldMaterial.01", replace to "NewMaterial.01"
- For "OldMaterial.02", replace to "NewMaterial.02"
- For "OldMaterial.03", replace to "NewMaterial.03"

And the script replace all materials for the match in the list.

That will be increase so much the workflow Sketchup - Blender!

Thanks for now!

Answer (score 2):

Every object has a list of materials it uses in it's [material_slots](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.material_slots) property, this is shown in the [material properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/material_panel.html), each slot contains the material used. By looping through this list you can change the material assigned to each slot.

I would setup a dictionary of old-to-new names to use for the conversion process.

```
import bpy

matnames = {
    'OldMaterial.01': 'NewMaterial.01',
    'OldMaterial.02': 'NewMaterial.02',
    'OldMaterial.03': 'NewMaterial.03',
    'OldMaterial.04': 'NewMaterial.04',
    'OldMaterial.05': 'NewMaterial.05',
    'OldMaterial.06': 'NewMaterial.06',
}

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    for slot in obj.material_slots:
        slot.material = bpy.data.materials[matnames[slot.material.name]]
```

Comment: Nice! I'm new Python's user, and don't know programing :(  But I trying to learn :D 

Thanks for all. But i have so many questions more hahahahhaa

I try run this script that u posted, but don't worked :/

In the line "matnames = { .....}" u are creanting a dictionary, right?

Comment: A good start would be spending an hour or two doing a getting started tutorial like the [official python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Yes matnames is a dictionary, it uses the name of the old mat as the key to retrieve the name of the new mat. Everything between `{}` is the contents of the dictionary, adjust the old name and new name on each line to match what you have.

Comment: @sambler Great answer! This was very helpful to me, as I had spent several hours struggling to write something similar. One thing I noticed and want to modify, is that while an object with materials (for example) R,G,B will get replaced with R_new, G_new, B_new... if an object has R,G_new, B, then material "B" won't get replaced because "G_new" isn't a match (it's only looking for R,G,B and stops at a non-match). Can you please teach how to skip over non-matches?

Comment: @Mentalist My first suggestion is to start with a full list, even if the replacement is the same as the original, go into blenders python console and type `bpy.data.materials.keys()` to get a complete list of material names. The other option, is after the second `for` add `if slot.material.name in matname.keys():` to only do the last command if a substitute exists. You could also put the last statement into a try block to catch errors and keep going, you only need pass in the except section.