# Working Pipeline with Imported Meshes?

Tags: materials, import, linked-data, data-blocks

im working with imported files (from differents architects) , and they like to do “updates” of the building model almost twice a day ,when im working on it in blender, doing texturing work , material work, lighting , camera, placing prop , rendering, ect ect … … …

so everytime the model need an update, i have to delete the building model , and re import the new version and start a quick render…

but eveytime i do that, i lose all my material replacement work, so i have to re-replace every original materials (multi users) of the imported mesh, with my own cycles ones , like i did first time , over and over again , twice or + a day ; with the 40+ materials ... its a waste of time

… there must be a solution somewhere to skip this part? right ?

---

*like :automatically replacing imported ugly materials from the imported house mesh to my custom cycles ones ? [didnt find anything]*

---

*like :changing only the data of my outdated model with the data of my new model while keeping the material info ? [not working]*

---

*like :puting the imported mesh into a "master import.blend" , linking it to another .blend , then changing material to local? [someone even told me its impossible?]*

---

ive been searching for one week now , didnt find anything but deads end.

could someone help me ?

Comment: It seems to be the [third time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111236/not-losing-material-attribution-when-changing-import) you [ask this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111922/update-imported-model-witouth-changing-materials), please don't post the same question multiple times. If you [get no answers edit your posts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) and provide more details.

Comment: There generally isn't a very elegant workflow for this, use library files you link references from to reduce placement work. If material slots don't change just link materials from the old mesh to the new one instead of manually reassigning them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not losing material attribution when changing import](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111236/not-losing-material-attribution-when-changing-import)

Comment: Sorry, nobody used to answer? I delete the post then this one is more clear... I will try your solution tomorrow

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/90375/935) has a script that will replace the imported materials with your cycles materials for every object in your blend. Just be sure to name your materials so they don't conflict with any imported ones.